# "Uncaught Reference Error: Model is not defined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>"

Tags: html, nodejs

En un proyecto de nodejs aparece este error: "Uncaught Reference Error: Model is not defined at HTMLDocument.". Model es una clase importada de otro archivo en el mismo módulo. El type="module" está activado en el html. Este es el código donde aparece el error:

```
import model from "./model.js"

import view from "./view.js"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const model = new Model()
    const view = new View()
    model.setView(view)
    view.setModel(model)
})
```

He comprobado el archivo model y está bien escrito.

Comment: Intenta nombrando `import Model from "./model.js"` y también `import View from "./view.js"`. Nótese que la primera esta en mayúsculas.

Comment: @Legna gracias, me ha servido, no sé como no me di cuenta

Comment: @DIEGONUSKU por favor traduce tu pregunta para evitar su cierre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta nombrando `import Model from "./model.js"` y también `import View from "./view.js"`. Nótese que la primera esta en mayúsculas.